# bulk insert using OCI

Tags: oracle-call-interface

I am currently inserting records one-by-one into a table from C++ code using OCI. The data is in a hashmap of structs, I iterate over the elements of the map, binding the attributes of the struct to the columns of a record in the table (e.g.

define insert query
use OCIBindByname( ) for all the columns of record
iterate over map
    assign bind variables as attributes of the struct
    OCIStmtExecute
end

This is pretty slow, so I'd like to speed up by doing a bulk insert. What is a good way to do this? Should I use an array of struct to insert all the records in one OCIStmtExecute? Do you have any example code which shows how to do this?

Answer (score 2):

[Here](https://github.com/gaiustech/ociml/blob/master/oci_bulkdml.c) is some sample code showing how I implemented this in [OCI*ML](http://gaiustech.github.com/ociml/). In summary, the way to do this is (say for a table with one column of integers):

1. `malloc()` a block of memory of `sizeof(int)` × the number of rows and populate it. This could be an array.
2. Call `OCIBindByPos()` with that pointer for `*valuep` and the size for `value_sz`.
3. Call `OCIStmtExecute()` with `iters` set to the number of rows from step 1

In my [experience](http://gaiustech.wordpress.com/2011/06/08/ociml-bulk-operations/), speedups of 100× are certainly possible.

Answer (score 1):

What you probably want to do is 'bulk inserts'. Bulk inserts in array are done by using ArrayBinds where you bind the data of the first row with the first structure of the array and set jumps, which generally is size of structure. After this you can just do statement execute with number of arrays. Multiple binds will create overheads, hence bulk inserts are used.

Answer (score 1):

```
bulk insert example.txt
by
{
delimeter=','  //  or any delimiter specified in your text files
size=200kb //or your size of text file
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use DPL(Direct Path Loading).
Refer to [docs.oracle.com](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28395/oci13obn.htm#g443680) for more info.